# Java: Creating an executable in bash/command line from several files and packages

Tags: java, bash, unix, javac

I've looked over the questions I could find in the search concerning javac, Java compilation and so on, but they either didn't answer this combination of questions, or the solutions didn't work.

I have a project that works and compiles fine in my IDE. However, it has to be compiled and executed through bash commands. Using an IDE, Ant, Maven or any other build tool is not an option. At best, I can use a makefile but from what I've gathered from concerning Java and make around here, this is generally a bad idea. The fact that I have absolutely no idea about Unix doesn't help the matter either.

My project consists of a good number classes split up into three packages, but as a last resort I could still dump it into one package if that'd make it any easier, but I've pretty much exhausted my options to try and solve this myself. Including the commands for Windows would be appreciated (because it would make it easier to test), but isn't necessary.

Comment: The `javac` and `jar` commands have nearly identical syntax both in Windows and in Unix.  The only differences are your source directories and, if you need a custom classpath, the path separators.  Setting aside bash scripts for the moment, have you tried running those two commands yourself?

Comment: Why is Ant or Maven not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling your classes in separate package like this

```
javac [path to folder1]/*.java [path to folder2]/*.java
```

OR

In unix,You can list down all `java` files in a single source file say `projectsource.txt`

and try following command

```
$ find -name "*.java" > projectsource.txt
$ javac @projectsource.txt
```